# UITableView row height not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a custom Cell. I have an array of dictionaries. For the dictionary values I need to create `UILable`s. Each cell may contained different number of `UILabel`s. So in my custom `UITableViewCell` class I have done like this.

```
- (void)generateCell {


BOOL isLandscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(vc.interfaceOrientation);
for (int i = 0; i < [orderMap count]; i++) {
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    lbl.tag = [[orderMap objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    [lbl setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];

}

if (isLandscape) {

}
else {
    [self setConstraintsForPortrait];
}
}

- (void)setConstraintsForPortrait {


double currentUsedWidth = 0;
double relativeWidthLimit = 1;
int reservedPaddingSpace = 20;
int usableScreenWidthPts = 0;
int xPositionStartingPoint = 15;
int xPosition = xPositionStartingPoint;
int yPosition = INDIVIDUAL_PADDING_PTS;
int fieldCounter = 0;
UIView *previousView;

for (UIView *vw in [self.contentView subviews]) {
    NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vw attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:(xPosition + INDIVIDUAL_PADDING_PTS)];
    NSLayoutConstraint *top;

    if (previousView == nil) {
        top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vw attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:INDIVIDUAL_PADDING_PTS];
    }
    else {
        top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vw attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:INDIVIDUAL_PADDING_PTS];
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint *trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vw attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:INDIVIDUAL_PADDING_PTS];
    if (fieldCounter >= [orderMap count]) {
        NSLayoutConstraint *bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vw attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:INDIVIDUAL_PADDING_PTS];

        [self.contentView addConstraint:bottom];
    }



    [self.contentView addConstraint:leading];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:top];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:trailing];
    previousView = vw;
}
```

}

And in my `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad` method I have done this.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tbl registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:metadataListTableIdentifier];
self.tbl.estimatedRowHeight = 200;
self.tbl.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
[self.tbl reloadData];
```

Why the cell height is not changing? Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After setting delegate and datasources of tableview, Try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension //return height size whichever you want
    }
```

or

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200 //return height size whichever you want
}
```

Comment: I commented those 2 lines and added these delegates. But no effect. still same :(

Comment: Then you need to check the constraint as its not proper and with priority.
if the constraints are proper then this code will work

Comment: And also check what you have set in xib or stroyboard for height of table view height it should be as same as height you want to set @myStack

Comment: I am not talking about height of table view I am talking about height of row in xib or storyboard

Comment: It has set to Automatic

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return [self getMessageSize:[[_arrCaseActivityList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"] Width:275];
}

-(float )getMessageSize :(NSString *)text Width :(float)textWidth
{
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:text
 attributes:@
 {
 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rubik-Regular" size:13.0]
 }];

    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){textWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
    CGSize finalSize = rect.size;
    return finalSize.height+75;

}
```

Comment: But If I set the constraints the cell size should change accordingly isn't it?

Comment: Remove custom Cell constraints and try it. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

click  + Drag your tableview and set viewcontroller view equal width and equal height

```
#pragma mark tableview delegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [DATA count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    PartyListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PartyListCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

  cell.textLabel.text = [DATA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 38.0;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   }

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *tableviewHeader = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PartyListHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return tableviewHeader;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 38.0;
}
```

click on button load you nib file

```
 if (popUpView== nil) {
        popUpView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PopupView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.view addSubview:popUpView];
        [popUpView setDelegate:self];
        [popUpView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }
```

Comment: I want to add UILabels dynamically. And different cell may contains different number of labels. So I can't use cell.labelname directly. I am adding those labels using a for loop

Comment: you dont need to loop for that just create a mutable array for data and give cell value to them like this

Comment: Even user can add new UILabel's once they added, tbl should reload and add the new label. If I didn't use a loop how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Provide proper constraints in Interface Builder eg. `leading, trailing` etc. and set `no of lines` for UILabel as **0**. Add the below code in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300 // estimated row height for performance improvement
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the function :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
```

instead of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
```

Make sure you are using the correct function.