# programmatically generate UITableviewCell with constraints which has dynamic heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

My iOS app has several `UIViewControllers` which include `UITableViews`. I have a single class called `ListScreenManager` and according to the passing data this class generates the cells for various `UITableView`s. This is one of table delegate implementations (cellForrowAtIndex).

```
static NSString *jobListTableIdentifier = @"JobListTableViewCell";

MetadataTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:jobListTableIdentifier];
NSMutableDictionary *dict;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
    dict = [theFilteredTaskData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else{
    dict = [theTaskData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
[MetrixListScreenManager setCellDataDictionary:dict];
if (cell == nil || cellReloadCount <= cellReloadLimit) {
    cell = [MetrixListScreenManager generateCellForListScreen:self withReuseIdentifier:jobListTableIdentifier];
    cellReloadCount++;
}

[SkinApplicationUITableViewController applySkinColorToRelevantControlsForCell:cell];

[MetrixListScreenManager populateCellDataForListScreen:self usingCell:cell andDataRow:dict];
```

in this `generateCellForListScreen` method I am generating UILabels/Buttons dynamicallly (multiple UILabels in a cell).What I want to do is make these `UILabels` dynamic height, setting up constraints and adjusting the `UITableViewCell` height according to the content height. I set leading, top, width constraints and now I have 2 problems.

1. How to make the `UILabel` dynamic height with these constraints?
2. How to make the `UITableViewCell` height according to the content height?

I made a prototype app just by adding 2 `UILabel`s which have leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints (These labels I generated in a separate class. Not inside the view controller which has my UITableView). Then I set table row height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and estimated row height to 200. But my row height just like 44 height. It looks like it doesn't know about the constraints. I am suspecting this is because I am generating those in a separate class. Am I correct? If so how can I overcome this issue?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Follow this [link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164319/programmatically-generate-uitableviewcell-with-constraints-which-has-dynamic-hei/48164392#48164392) you can get your answer.

Comment: @kalpeshsatasiya which link? This is redirecting me to my question

Comment: are you get a link?

Comment: seems you have added the link of my question @kalpeshsatasiya

Comment: sorry follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936372/5715863

Comment: @you got a solution or not?

Comment: It is the way I have implemented. Because of some reason I want to convert it into auto layout. @kalpeshsatasiya

Comment: This is auto layout code it will really useful you.

Comment: @kalpeshsatasiya which one?

Comment: I sent a link please check above fifth comment

Comment: Yeas I am talking about that link.

Comment: @kalpeshsatasiya And it is not auto layout